# Websocket tests from batch file with tyrus CLI

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, websocket, tyrus

I'm trying to implement a small test for my websocket server and I found [Tyrus CLI](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/websocket_command_line_client). When I ran it, it seemed to get the input from command line, so in the next step I tried

```
echo ping | java -jar ./tyrus-client-cli-1.1.jar ws://<myIP>:<port>/<url>
```

The connection is opened, but the ping is not performed. I also tried moving the `ping` command into a text file and doing

```
java -jar ./tyrus-client-cli-1.1.jar ws://<myIP>:<port>/<url> < commands.txt
```

but it also opens the connection only, not performing any command.

How can I use Tyrus CLI from command line without manually entering the commands?